# EXC_BAD_ACCES puchviewcontroller tableview

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, pushviewcontroller

I have got a problem when I compile my project for ios5. This code below works on ios4.3. During runtime, the Kernel throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS Mach exception on this line :

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:choixQuotidienTableViewController animated:YES];
```

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath on my tableview :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    // requête avec la langue choisie
    NSArray *codes = [arrayLangages valueForKey:@"code"];
    NSString *codeSelect = [codes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //NSLog(@"selected code : %@", codeSelect);

    // init table view Choix Quotidien
        ChoixQuotidienTableViewController *choixQuotidienTableViewController = [[ChoixQuotidienTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain andCode:codeSelect];

    //choixQuotidienTableViewController.fromLangue = resultsArrayKioskLangue;
    if([self navigationController] == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"navigationController IS NIL!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Nav controller IS OK!");
        if(!choixQuotidienTableViewController)
        {
            NSLog(@"choixcontroller IS NIL!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"choix controller IS OK!");
            [[self navigationController] pushViewController:choixQuotidienTableViewController animated:YES];
        }
    }
    choixQuotidienTableViewController = nil;
}
```

Could you please helpl me ? is something change in ios5 ?

Thanks !

UPDATE : OK something new ... : I've used profil > Zombies. This tools showed me an error in [ChoixQuotidienTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] ... CRAZY !

I used a custom cell ... when I corrige this it works ...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `[self navigationController]` can be non-nil and still give you bad access. Try to send another message to it (e.g. `description` or `viewControllers` and see what you get. Also, try including it in your log statement.

Comment: I've done this : NSArray *viewControllerArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
        int nbViewController = [viewControllerArray count];
        NSLog(@"%i controllers", nbViewController); and I've got 1 controllers in viewControllersArray

Comment: 2011-10-26 11:57:57.490 LoungeUp[19700:10103] Nav controller IS OK!
2011-10-26 11:57:57.490 LoungeUp[19700:10103] 1 controllers
2011-10-26 11:57:57.490 LoungeUp[19700:10103] choix controller IS OK!
(gdb)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to say without more code.

The BAD_ACCESS is not produced by this code. But be aware that `choixQuotidienTableViewController` will be leaking if you don't release it (except if you use ARC).

Ensure that `[self navigationController]` returns a valid object that has not been released.

Also the debugger stack trace might help.

Comment: Hello Nicolas & Thanks for your answer. Are my comments on the others answers ok for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try 
    `[choixQuotidienTableViewController release];`
instead of
    `choixQuotidienTableViewController = nil;` ?

Comment: First, you should tell us what your debugger is saying about [self navigationController]. For example, you should put a breakpoint at this line and ask "po [self navigationController]" to your debugger, it'll tell you if your controller is not a valid object

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I didn't know about po command ! in my case po command gave me : (gdb) po [self navigationController]
<UINavigationController: 0x6b75a20>

Comment: Ok then your navigationController seems to be a valid object. Can you show me your methods -(id)initWithStyle:andCode: ?

Comment: - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style andCode:(NSString *)code
{
    UIColor *myColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self)
    {
        codeReq = code;
        //NSLog(@" codereq from choix quotidien : %@", codeReq);
        
        self.title = @"Kiosque";
        self.view.backgroundColor = myColor;
    }
    return self;
}